# "TypeScript error: Argument of type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'"

Tags: typescript, canvas

```
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
if (ctx === null) {
        throw new Error("ctx can not be null")
}

ctx.strokeStyle = 'black'
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => startDrawing(ctx, e))
```

I get a typescript error at ctx from the startDrawing function, saying:

```
Argument of type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'.
```

but not at `ctx.strokeStyle`.
Why is that?
Shouldn't the if-clause make sure that `ctx` is not null?

Comment: The reference in question is inside a callback which will be called somewhere in the future. For the compiler there is no guarantee, that `ctx` won't be changed to `null` in the meantime

Comment: Okay and what is the best way to tell the compiler that ctx won't be changed?

Comment: The simplest is probably the non-null-assertion. `startDrawing(ctx!, e)`